# Using powershell to change attribute

Tags: powershell, active-directory, command

First:
I am complete new to Powershell-Scripting.

Want to change the attribute "preferredLanguage" from some Users via powershell.
The users are written in txt-file
testUser000
testUser001 and so on

My first try was to become a list with users and some attributes:

```
     $users = ForEach ($user in $(Get-Content C:\Temp\users.txt)) {

    Get-AdUser $user -Properties Department, Mail, preferredLanguage

}

 $users |
 Select-Object SamAccountName,Department,Mail, preferredLanguage |
 Export-CSV -Path C:\temp\outputUsers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

That worked so far:

"SamAccountName","Department","Mail","preferredLanguage"
"tesUser000","dept1","testUser000@domain.com","DE"
"testUser0001","dept2","testUser001@domain.com",

testUser000 has an entry in preferredLanguage
testUser0001 has no entry
That's ok. When I have completed the users.txt, there are more than 100 users without an entry in 'preferredLanguage'

Now I want to change the preferredLanguage and with some investigation in the Internet I made this:

```
$users = ForEach ($user in $(Get-Content C:\Temp\users.txt)) {

    Get-AdUser $user -Properties Department, Mail, preferredLanguage

}

 $users |
 Set-AdUser $users -Replace @preferredLanguage="DE" |

 Select-Object SamAccountName,Department,Mail, preferredLanguage |
 Export-CSV -Path C:\temp\outputUsers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

When I understand this script right, then it get from my txt-File every user in it with the given attributes then it changes the attribute 'preferredLanguage' from the users in the txt-file and then it select it again then it will save the output in a csv-file.

Maybe someone can look over the script and would be so kind and give me feedback about it or a better way, because Iam too scary to use this script on the AD-Server.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few things:

- `Get-AdUser $user` means you must be sure the user with that identity exists or an exception will be thrown
- the syntax for the `-Replace` operator should be `@{preferredLanguage="DE"}`
- Set-ADUser does not generate any output unless the `-PassThru` parameter is used.
- if you use `ForEach-Object`, you can do all this in one loop

Try changing the code with this:

```
(Get-Content C:\Temp\users.txt) | ForEach-Object {
    $account = Get-AdUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$_'" -Properties Department, Mail, preferredLanguage -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($account) {
        $account | Set-AdUser -Replace @{preferredLanguage="DE"} -PassThru |
        Select-Object SamAccountName,Department,Mail, preferredLanguage
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "User '$_' does not exist"
    }
} | Export-CSV -Path C:\temp\outputUsers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It looks way better than mine.